# Play Framework date in view

Tags: playframework

What is the best way to add a dynamic date (year) in a Play Framework view.  I want to add a copyright at the bottom of the page, but I do not want to hard code `2011`.

```
<p> &copy; 2011 </p>
```

How can I get 2011 to always be the current year?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For Play 1.x try this

```
${new Date().format("yyyy")}
```

For Play 2.x users, the synyax is subtly different

```
@(new Date().format("yyyy"))
```

It creates the current date, and formats it (using the [Format JavaExtension](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/javaextensions#format) for the Date object).

Comment: This answer is so simple; I am slightly embarrassed. Thank you.  It does work.

Comment: Only easy when you know how. Read up on the other Java Extensions. They are really powerful, and you can even write your own.

Comment: thank you very much for this and thank you for asking the question. you've helped others see it as easy now.

Comment: I would also like to point out that for me I had to format the scala statement using the @ symbol and parenthesis like this  - @(new Date().format("yyyy")) instead of ${new Date().format("yyyy")}

Comment: yes, this answer was in the play 1.x days. I'll update the answer to reflect play2.x also

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to add 
`@import java.util.Date` in template file for `@(new Date().format("yyyy"))` to work

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: Wish i could comment. i need a reputation of 50 to comment. Just wanted to help anyway i could

Comment: We appreciate all the help we can get -- Unfortunately, if you can't comment yet, the best action is to do nothing. Creating an answer that isn't actually an answer puts a cog in the system.